# SimpleCursor Adapter ,LoaderManager IllegalState Exception or StaleData Exception

Tags: android

I have a gridview populated with the help of SimpleCursor adapter and Loader Manager(Support v4). The content of the gridview is fetched from web server with the help of pagination. If i fastly switch the view between detailed view and gridview during the webservice call i got illegalstate error /StaleDataException.

```
05-15 00:36:54.114: E/AndroidRuntime(10656): java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: SELECT * FROM product_list WHERE (url =  ? )
05-15 00:36:54.114: E/AndroidRuntime(10656):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
05-15 00:36:54.114: E/AndroidRuntime(10656):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:58)
05-15 00:36:54.114: E/AndroidRuntime(10656):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:151)
05-15 00:36:54.114: E/AndroidRuntime(10656):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.onMove(SQLiteCursor.java:124)
05-15 00:36:54.114: E/AndroidRuntime(10656):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:213)
05-15 00:36:54.114: E/AndroidRuntime(10656):    at android.database.CursorWrapper.moveToPosition(CursorWrapper.java:162)
05-15 00:36:54.114: E/AndroidRuntime(10656):    at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:247)
05-15 00:36:54.114: E/AndroidRuntime(10656):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2452)
05-15 00:36:54.114: E/AndroidRuntime(10656):    at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1331
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to add adapter.swapcursor(null) in the resetLoader callback?
I encountered the same log while this was missing and opening + closing the listfragment several times..